# PHP Regular Expressions Basics

Tags: php, regex

I am new to the world of coding as well as PHP and am having a hard time understanding how regular expressions are read.

For example, I constructed the simple regular expression below that is a weak attempt to validate an email address.

The email address - **test@test.com**

The regular expression - `^([0-9a-zA-Z])+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$`

What I would like to understand is how each segment of the email address in this example is dealt with and read e.g.

1. test would be considered as segment 1,
2. @ would be considered the second segment,
3. the periond(.) would be considered the third segment,
4. etc

Obviously if I introduce an additional segment to the equation e.g. test-123 the regular expression fails.

Comment: Please see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for a more robust email validation regex. And check out my favourite spam link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some nice tools to analyze regular expressions. (But there are also online tools.)

Comment: @mario - Thanks. I am not looking for a tool per se. I know there any thousands of them. I am looking at how to write regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the basics are

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z])+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

^ matches start of string
() matches a segment which you can extract and use, if you were using preg_match for example

([0-9a-zA-Z])+ means it will match 1 or more of those characters specifed only
for an email address there are other chars that are valid, you should read the email RFC if you want to get into that detail
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

there are alternative ways of doing this, eg if you used the /i modifier at the end of your pattern you can make it case insensitive, and then you don't need to specify both a-z and A-Z

```
/^([0-9a-z])+@([-0-9a-z]+[.])+[a-z]{2,6}$/i
```

the @ symbol is pretty obvious, a necessary part of the email address (in external systems, internal email doesn't always need an @ as it can default to the internal domain)

([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+
this part matches the main part of the domain, I notice you have included hyphen - in the charset this time. also I am thinking you should have \. rather then just . by itself, as . matches anything, not fullstop as you would expect.

so it would match 1 or more of these characters [-0-9a-zA-Z], followed by any character at all

[a-zA-Z]{2,6}
matches [a-zA-Z] with minimum length of 2, and max length 6

$ matches then end of the string
if you had spaces after end of the email address it would fail validation, so you would need to trim it first in that case

matching an email address is actually not an easy thing to start with as there are quite a number of variations that are all valid

for example these could all be valid email addresses
bumperbox
bumperbox@invalid.com
bumper-box@invalid.com
bumperbox@invalid.co.uk
bumper.box@subdomain.invalid.school.nz

Your best bet is to use one of the already established email validation patterns available around the web, there are a few discussions about email validation in the php manual under preg_match, etc

you can also use functions such as filter_var if you have a recent (5.2+) version of php
http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Thanks. What I don't quite follow is the definition of a 'segment'. For example what in `test@test.com` constitutes a segment and if so how many segments are there?

Comment: 2 ways of looking at it. the () indicate segments in regex language. or if you want to break the email down, you would have the first bit, the @ symbol, followed by a domain name.

Comment: Thanks. So if I had an email address test-123@test.com I would require 2 segments for the first part of the email address e.g. test[segment1]-123[segement2]? Is that right? Now if that is correct how I extend that understanding to other strings. For example I know that I can use htmlentities to return the HTML tags as opposed to the page rendering them so if I had the string <html><head><title>Sample</title></head><body></body></html>, how would I remove all tags? Would < be segment one, html segment two, > segment three, etc?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I want understand how a regular expression interprets my constructed code.

Comment: basically you want to split the text into parts/segments you know are the same all the time, and parts that change. for your html string you can make some rough assumptions (as html is hard to regex also).  you can assume all html parts start the < and end with >, so your regex would look something like this preg_replace("/<.+?>/", ''); .+ matches anything between the angle brackets, ? means non-greedy. it will stop as soon as it finds the first closing > otherwise it will match the last one on the page and remove everything in between.

Answer (score 0):

`test-123@test.com` would fail as there's no `-` in your regex for that component of the email. It may look like there isn't, but there really isn't. When you do `[a-z]` in a regex, it is quite literally the equivalent of saying `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`, with nary a `-` in sight.

If you want to allow a dash in the first part of your email address, you'd need:

```
`[a-zA-Z0-9\-]`
```

Notice the backslash (`\`), which ESCAPES the dash so it loses its metacharacter status (aka "special") and becomes a character like any other.

Comment: Yes, I know that `test-123@test.com` fails. What my question is how do you read a string and decide what is the first part, what is the second part, etc. For example in the email address `test@test.com`, would `test` be considered the first part, `@` the second part, etc?

Comment: I'd suggest using perl. it's got a built in regex debugger which lets you see the stages the engine went through while it's trying to establish a match: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Debugging-regular-expressions

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it online or using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions don't have "segments". The engine goes through the string trying to find matching sequences of characters. Your perception of "segments" here is created in your mind because the `@` (and lack of `.` in the final capture) act as anchors, setting certain criteria for certain parts of any matching input.

Use [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) to see how matches are found.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Thanks. I did have a look at regexpal.com however that still doesn't explain how I match or replace a particular string if I don't know the 'segments'. For example, if I wanted to match .jpg in my regular expression, I would imagine the regular expression would have to find .jpg in the file name `this is a sample jpg.jpg`

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I did read the first sentence. Okay rather than imagining segments, how else can I construct the appropriate regular expression? I would welcome any suggestions and examples.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Construct a question clearly stating what inputs you do and do not want to match, and what you tried so far, and perhaps someone can help you come up with an expression. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Thanks. I don't want to be trying expressions without knowing how they work. If you look at my example `jpg`, how would you construct an expresion?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: That's really a new question, and it probably needs more information (as described above).

Comment: the part that doesn't change would be the extension eg .jpg at the end of the string so match around that. /^.+\.jpg$/i (use the /i modifier because it could be .JPG or .jpg, etc