# Regular expression for WD502

Tags: regex

I am working on dreamweaver v12 and testing script on chrome
I want the text to be in the form as shown:

```
 "E or W  A to F and 3 numbers"
```

For example: `WD502`

My regular expression is this:

```
/([EW]|[ew])([A-F]|[a-f])([0-9]{3})/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**Regular Expressions Basics**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5862945/1020526)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Give more precisions in your question: language, method you use...

Comment: Your regex looks fine (as was mentioned in the answers, you might want to add anchors to avoid false positives). Please provide additional information - which programming language are you using? Also, add the code snippet you're using to create your regex and for testing the match.

Comment: Show the whole part of code where your regex is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use anchors to ensure that the pattern begins at the start of the string and finish at the end of the string:

```
/^([EW])([A-F])([0-9]{3})$/i
```

`^` start of the string

`$` end of the string

the i modifier makes the pattern case-insensitive. But if your regex flavor doesn't support it, you can write:

```
/^([EWew])([A-Fa-f])([0-9]{3})$/
```

Perhaps (since don't give us more precisions), you don't need to use delimiters with your flavor, so try without:

```
^([EWew])([A-Fa-f])([0-9]{3})$
```

Comment: I did this but it is still returning false

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
/^[EW][A-F]\d\d\d$/i
```

Answer (score -1):

you have forgotten an or between E or W.

```
^([E|W]|[e|w])([A-F])([0-9]{3})$
```

Comment: argh!! `|` is seen as a literal character inside a character class and it looses its "or" meaning.

Comment: A bracket expression, matches a single character that is contained within the brackets. No need of |. `[A-F]` is the same as `[ABCDEF]`